# python motor create_index doesnt delete raw after expired time

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-asyncio

I have the following test in my project:

```
async def test_expire_at(
        aiohttp_client, mongo_collection):

    await mongo_collection.delete_many({})

    await mongo_collection.create_index([("expireAt", 1)],
                                        expireAfterSeconds=0)

    expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=5)

    await mongo_collection.update_one(
        {'key': '123'},
        {
            "$set":
                {
                    'key': '123',
                    'data': {},
                    'expireAt': expire
                }
        },
        upsert=True)

    await asyncio.sleep(10)

    count = await mongo_collection.count()
    assert count == 0
```

I expected that after `count` should be equal `0` because ttl index will remove the raw after 5 seconds. I use `motor==1.2.1`, and the latest docker image **https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/ . I have no idea what's could be wrong there :) 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The TTL scheduler only runs about "once a minute" or so. 5 seconds is far to granular to effect immediately. If you need that granular an operation, then you need to set up your own "cron like" scheduling yourself within your program.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks! I expected that mongo will not show expired data because there already index, and it's easy to check.